# wpf Customizing Calendar Control add Toggle button to date

Tags: c#, wpf

Sorry for my bad english (thank you google translate).

I want customize WPF `Calendar` control. I've added a `Toggle` button to the day value (in `ControlTemplate`), but I can't press the button in my application.

When the mouse cursor is over the button, it responds (in the pictured example, when choosing the date: May 7), but I cannot click `Left Mouse Click`. However, as you can see in the picture 2, when on May 8, if I use keyboard "Shift + Tab" through the switch to a `Toggle` button I can push the keyboard "space", but not the left mouse button. I think that is where the interception of the left mouse button press happens.

[image: Calendar image: May 7th]

[image: Calendar image: May 8th]

```
<StackPanel Margin="5,0,5,0" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"> 
   <ToggleButton x:Name="btnToggleT" Height="25" Width="25" Content="T" 
      HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="5,0,5,0" 
      IsThreeState="True" FontSize="12" /> 
   <ToggleButton x:Name="btnToggleS" Height="25" Width="25" Content="S" 
      HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="5,0,5,0" 
      IsThreeState="True" FontSize="12" /> 
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Hi! Please show the related xaml so people can help you out.

Comment: https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/develop/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.Calendar.xaml

Comment: I add in <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CalendarDayButton}">

Comment: <StackPanel Margin="5,0,5,0" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
<ToggleButton x:Name="btnToggleT" Height="25" Width="25" Content="T" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="5,0,5,0" IsThreeState="True" FontSize="12" />
<ToggleButton x:Name="btnToggleS" Height="25" Width="25" Content="S" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="5,0,5,0" IsThreeState="True"  FontSize="12" />
</StackPanel>

Comment: @NickFedorov, for future, edit your original question with the additional details others request vs comments which can get lengthy.  BTW, welcome to S/O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `ClickMode="Press"` to your toggle buttons, and they will be clicked with the mouse.

It seems that the `CalendarDayButton`'s `ClickMode` is set to `Press`, and your `ToggleButton`'s `ClickMode` is set to `Release`. So the event gets handled on the calendar button, and is your buttons never get the required mouse event.

Comment: Thanks!! It was just what I needed.